# What do you call the front fans of an old aircraft?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the front fans of an old aircraft? Is it called a fan or something else? I couldn't find the technical term used for this.

Comment: Did you try a bilingual dictionary?  Often single word requests can be most quickly answered by looking up the word in an (other language)-English dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

They are typically called propellers.
[Cambridge Dictionary: propeller](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/propeller)

Comment: Sometimes abbreviated *props*.

Comment: They are also called 'airscrews'.